# Is there a key in the Windows registry which indicates "this computer is a laptop"

Tags: c#, windows, registry

In a c# software , I must identify if the computer is a laptop or not
I searched and I didn't found any response about a value which indicates this computer is a laptop
And if there is no way to do that in the registry, is it possible to do it In another way?

Comment: You could check if it has a battery... Don't know what would happen if you remove the battery from the laptop

Comment: I don't think. You can analyse the presence and properties of a power battery, and also computers brand names and models, like hardware info software do.

Comment: There is a type property in the WMI `Win32_ComputerSystem` class.  Probably as accurate as the quality of the system allows

Comment: What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable asks a good question. If you tell why you think you need to do this, this may result into better solutions. Why do you care if the computer is a laptop or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the following PowerShell script from your C# code to check:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PCSystemtype
```

If the output is 2, it equals Mobile or Laptop, 1 is desktop

Found here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/registry-entry-to-determine-laptop-or-a-desktop/d5fc19c0-c279-4227-9a27-85aabe56e031?auth=1